# How to Build an Optimized Battle Cleric?

Tags: dnd-5e

I am a 3.5/Pathfinder player that will be playing in my first 5e campaign soon.  I was wondering how one would go about building an optimized battle cleric.  I don't need to know every spell that would be good for a cleric; I'm going to use my 3.5/PF knowledge to fill at least some of the blanks.  What I want is a general overview of what feats, spells, and items would help a generalist cleric become a good battle cleric.

In particular, in terms of spells, I am looking for the best buffing spells that the cleric spell list has to offer.  In terms of feats and equipment, I would like some suggestions that would help me create a well-armored, melee-oriented character.

Comment: If you have any suggestions on how to make my question better, please feel free to tell me.  This is the first optimization question I made on StackExchange.

Comment: Could you expand upon what "battle cleric" means? I have some general ideas but they are informed by 4e and 5e and not by 3.5 or PF. What type of spells does that mean (attack spells/healing/buffing/some combo thereof)? Are you looking to be primarily melee based? heavy armor?

Comment: Considering this is D&D, nearly every cleric is a battle cleric in some way. Please do be more specific about what you want to do with them precisely!

Comment: Yes, I mean primarily melee-based with heavy armor.  Would including that information narrow the question enough to fit the site's specifications?

Comment: Alright follow up question, why cleric vs paladin?

Comment: You may run into trouble using your 3.5/PF knowledge in 5e. It is only superficially similar in places, and proceeding as if those superficialities are more than skin-deep will probably make you hate 5e. For one example: you're already assuming that clerics are best played as buffers.

Comment: Should I not assume that buffing is the best way to increase my melee capabilities?  Or should I be questioning whether melee is the best means to play a battle cleric altogether?

Comment: Those are both 3.x archetypes for clerics. On what are you basing the idea that they work for 5e clerics? (They might, but might not.) Giving us some idea of why you're asking for what you're asking for would help a lot. "I'm just assuming this is a good idea" isn't a great way to try to get an *optimised* character, after all. What are you basing your character direction on?

Comment: If by "character direction" you mean "what I want my character to do", I would like her to be able to hit things hard but also have some versatility when a situation calls for a more non-combat based solution.

Comment: Thinking about it, I think your problem here is that you don't really understand what you're asking. Maybe if you read the relevant bits of the PHB, you could come back with a more specific question?

Comment: I concur, asking an optimization question without even reading the PHB is off topic and a poor use of peoples' time. This question will remain closed, come back and ask specific questions based on what you find when you have learned the game system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If it has to be a Cleric, you should build a Cleric of the War Domain.**

All clerics  get access to medium armor, shields and simple weapons. Each cleric domain gives you different features as you level up (in addition to the core class features) as well as specific spell lists. The War domain gives you proficiency with heavy armor and military weapons as well as an ability similar to the martial classes extra attack but restricted to uses per day. the war cleric's spell lists adds spells to buff your AC (or react to an attack) as well as combat utility spells like magic weapon.

**What you really want however, is a Paladin.**

While the Cleric is a magic user in medium armor with specialization in close-combat as a secondary choice, the Paladin is about close-combat first and foremost and all spell casting and features serve to support that role. Paladins start with proficiency in all weapons and armor and they also quickly gain a fighting style improving their melee attacks. Each paladin Oath lets you specialized in the type of spells you would like, but all paladins can use their spell slots to smite after successfully hitting enemies to add lots of damage. The paladin also has a class hit die of a d10 vs. the cleric's d8.

Comment: I have a couple of follow up questions: 1. Does the paladin have the versatility to conjure up solutions when a situation does not call for combat?, and 2. Do I have to be a certain alignment to play as a Paladin?

Comment: @user3735278 Have you read the PHB yet?

Comment: To be honest, I have yet to do so.  I'm just gathering information on what to look out for at the moment.

Comment: @user3735278 There are no alignment restrictions on any class in 5e. Your first question isn't really answerable, there are a lot of different non-combat situations, some of which a Paladin can deal with and some they can't.

Comment: Is there a way to ask "What are some good non-combat spells on the Paladin's spell list?" in an answerable way?

Comment: @user3735278 Probably not, no. The answer to that would be a list of every spell the Paladin has that is applicable to a non-combat situation. You should probably just **read the PHB.**

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll accept this answer in a day or two if no one else has a more compelling answer.  This is a pretty good answer all-around, though, at any rate.

Comment: Clerics of War get access to Heavy Armor and Martial Weapons, making the choice of Paladin as strictly superior moot. They are on equal footing, the Paladin being more consistent in Melee, and the cleric being more versatile.